# How to wipe some contents of boost managed_shared_memory?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, interprocess

The `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory` [manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html) and [most other](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html) resources I checked always shows examples where there is a parent process and a bunch of children spawned by it.

In my case, I have several processes spawned by a third part application and I can only control the "children". It means I cannot have a central brain to allocate and deallocate the shared memory segment. All my processes must be able to do so (**Therefore, I can't erase data on exit**).

My idea was to `open_or_create` a segment and, using a lock stored (`find_or_construct`'ed) in this area, I check a certain hash to see if the memory area was created by this same software version.

If this is not true, the memory segment must be wiped to avoid breaking code.

Ideally, I would want to keep the lock object because there could be other processes already waiting on it.

Things I though:

1. List all object names and delete all but the lock.

   - This can not be done because the objects might be using different implementations
   - Also I couldn't find where to list the names.
2. Use `shared_memory_object::truncate`

   - I could not find much about it
   - By using a `managed_shared_memory`, I don't know how reliable it would be because I'm not sure the lock was the first allocated data.
3. Refcount the processes and wipe data on last one

   - Prone to fatal termination problems.
4. Use a separated shared memory area just for this bookkeeping.

   - Sounds reasonable, but overkill?

Any suggestions or insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a "shared ownership" scenario.

What you'd usually think of in such a scenario, would be *shared pointers*:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/interprocess_smart_ptr.html#interprocess.interprocess_smart_ptr.shared_ptr

Interprocess has specialized shared pointers (and ditto `make_shared`) for exactly this purpose.

Creating the shared memory realm can be done "optimistically" from each participating process (`open_or_create`). Note that creation needs to be synchronized. Further segment manager operations are usually already implicitly synchronized:

> Whenever the same managed shared memory is accessed from different processes, operations such as creating, finding, and destroying objects are automatically synchronized. If two programs try to create objects with different names in the managed shared memory, the access is serialized accordingly. To execute multiple operations at one time without being interrupted by operations from a different process, use the member function `atomic_func()` (see [Example 33.11](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-managed-shared-memory)).

Comment: I am more interested about memory integrity and how/when should I delete stuf. I ended up doing my option 4 (although some of the same problems still arise). Using `atomic_func()` sound better than my idea of creating a lock inside the shared memory, but I believe both approaches would give the same result (just less boilerplate, which is great). +1

Comment: I don't get it. The memory integrity using the shared pointer/weak pointer approach is is ***strictly better*** than anything you can arrange for manually. There will always be the loophole of abnormal process terminations (e.g. SIGKILL) but that's independent and can only be "solved" using disk based transactions (intent logging). Beyond the topic here

Comment: Because the memory outlives **all** my processes, I can have issues inbetween runs. Some data structures might change and, of course, abnormal terminations are not ruled out.